# Changing colour of point based on null value using Arcade Expression in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, expression, arcade

I have a map in ArcGIS Online with a point layer showing lighting assets. These are symbolised based on unique type (post = circle, column = square).

The user will update a separate field to have a unique alphanumeric ID for each Asset.

I would like to use an Arcade expression to change the colour of the points when the field value changes from null to its new ID.

E.g. If the Unique ID is null the point colour is red, if the Unique ID is not null then colour green.

I haven't used the Arcade language before and cannot find guidance online for this particular query.

Comment: possible solution- create two layers in the web map. base map is all red points and the layer on top will show green points if value != null.

Comment: @Joe - Thank you for the idea. Can you explain further please? I'm not clear on how/where to apply the expression value != null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?webmap=93bca1dfa0d14676adbefe160c7a8c3b

```
//check the id for null values
IF (isEmpty($feature.id)) { 
    //id is null check the type
    When($feature.type == 'Male', "Male with no ID", 
    $feature.type == 'Female', 'Female with no ID', 
    "Other")

} else {
        //id is good check the type
    When($feature.type == 'Male', "Male with ID", 
    $feature.type == 'Female', 'Female with ID', 
    "Other")

}
```

Comment: this checks if the feature id is null?

Comment: so isEmpty($feature.fieldname) would check the value of that field for null or empty strings. field.id is just a field in my sample.

Comment: ok cool and the 2nd string parameter is the label for these features? nice man ARCADE is something i want to start learning

Comment: Yup check out GeoNet and the blog sites, https://geonet.esri.com/community/gis/web-gis/arcgisonline/blog/2017/07/18/conditional-field-display-with-arcade-in-pop-ups , https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/

Comment: @RussRoberts - Legend! I made one mistake - I had to export the shapefile to fgdb as obviously shp's do not allow null values, so when applying the expression it showed everything as having an ID. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RussRoberts The only oddity is that when I turn on edit mode within my web mapping application (Web AppBuilder) the symbology reverts to a single symbol. Do you know if this is normal behaviour, or is there a way to change it?

Comment: For those who come across this issue in the future - the behaviour described above does not occur when using the Smart Editor widget.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue.
I used

```
IIF(IsEmpty($feature.ID), "NOT FILLED", "FILLED")
```